# Expanding two parameter packs in unison

Tags: c++, templates

I am updating some elements (selected at compile time) in a container using values from another container. Right now I am doing something akin to this:

```
template<size_t... indices>
void update(value_t values, index_sequence<indices...>) {
  int i = 0; 
  ((data[indices] = values[i++], ...);
}
```

Question: is it possible to avoid the use of variable `i` by using another compile-time sequence, e.g. something along the following lines:

```
template<size_t... indices1, size_t... indices2>
void update_helper(value_t values, index_sequence<indices1...>, 
                                   index_sequence<indices2...>) {
  static_assert(sizeof...(indices1) == sizeof...(indices2), "");
  ((data[indices1] = values[indices2], ...);
} 

template<size_t... indices>
void update(value_t values, index_sequence<indices...> i) {
  update_helper(values, i, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(indices)>{});
}
```

Comment: Note you don't need the empty string in the `static_assert`. You're using fold expressions, which means you're compiling in C++17 mode (or an experimental C++20-like mode), and C++17 added a one argument form of `static_assert`.

Comment: @aschepler thank you for pointing this out, its a habit by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible (as long as they have the same size).

```
template <size_t... indices1, size_t... indices2>
void update_helper(value_t values,
                   index_sequence<indices1...>, 
                   index_sequence<indices2...>)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(indices1) == sizeof...(indices2), "");
    ((data[indices1] = values[indices2], ...);
}
```

is valid.

Comment: Silly of me, I should have tried it out before assuming that it wouldn't work out of the box. At any rate, thank you!